# Mac OS Android Studio Menu, no longer on top. How to fix it?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, intellij-idea

Hope this is not a dumb question. I search and can't find any answer to it.

Any application on Mac OS, it's menu is normally on the top.
However, after a sudden exit of my Android Studio, my menu now is attached to the Application instead of at the top (i.e. the same place where `Android Studio` is shown as per the diagram below). How could I set it back there?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be related to the latest issue on macOS beta related to the screen menu in the Java applications. You can find more details in [JRE-434](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-434).

For IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio this behavior is controlled by the following option (`Help` | **Edit Custom VM Options**):

`-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=false`

Changing it to `true` could bring the menu back unless your system is affected by the bug mentioned above, otherwise you will have no menu at all.

Comment: I think you're right, the Edit Custom VM Options when click, state that `File " does not exist. Create?` When I click Yes, it states `Error. Cannot create file ": (No such file or directory)`. How should I proceed to fix the issue.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869. It's probably a permission issue.

Comment: Can't really get to that. To make things easy, I uninstall my AS3.0 and reinstall it. All goes back to normal. Indeed a corrupted app setting I believe. Thanks!